# Why setw and width does not work for ostringstream?

Tags: c++, string, stl, iostream

I have the following code:

```
template<typename _Tp>
std::string string_from_number(_Tp number, int precision = 5)
{
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss.width(precision+1);
  oss<<number;
  return oss.str();
}
```

However the string length is not 5 as expected, but stays the default.
Replacing `oss.width` to `oss<<std::setw` does not work either.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The problem appears clearly if the number is of double type say 0.123456789.

Comment: The default 8?  Why is the default 8?  And can you show a complete code example, your expected output and your actual output?  Because for me, this does exactly what I would expect it to do.  It returns a string of length 6, when the default value of 5 is used.  [Demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/61e41e6cdc67bbdbd87261c0bedd9210)

Comment: Are you talking about the number of digits displayed in a floating point number?  The function you want is [`precision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision), not `width`.

Comment: You are right, I think the default could be 9. Thanks for testing, even with your code if I use a double as input, and say 2 for precision, it sticks to the default width...

Comment: Yes, in the mean time I figured out on some forum, too, and `precision` works now fine. If you put it in an answer, I'll vote up and accept it. ;) Thanks for the effort again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For controlling the number of digits displayed in a floating point number, the function you want is `precision`, not `width`.  If you want to be sure you get the number displayed in fixed notation (rather than scientific) also look at the format flag `fixed`, used with the `setf` member function.

Comment: If `precision` is for the total number of digits, how do I set the number of digits after decimal?

Comment: That'd be with the flag `floatfield`.